# Is this a photograph of 23 year old Joseph Stalin?

Tags: history, photography

I've seen the following picture on multiple websites including these two, [Is this really Joseph Stalin as a young man?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=711893)  and [Beware, girls: even Stalin could switch on the 'charm offensive'](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/beware-girls-even-stalin-could-switch-on-the-charm-offensive-20160828-gr2xe4.html), saying that it depicts a young Joseph Stalin. There are many physical similarities to later photographs of him, especially his eyebrows.

[image: Supposed picture of 23 year old Joseph Stalin]

Recently I've seen on a few websites that this is supposedly another person that looked similar to young Stalin and that the picture was released for propaganda purposes.

Who is really on this photograph?

Comment: Can you at least link the sites you mentioned? Where did you find the picture?

Comment: Two links: [Straight dope discussion](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=711893), [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/beware-girls-even-stalin-could-switch-on-the-charm-offensive-20160828-gr2xe4.html).
I can't really find an original source at the moment.

Comment: Why do you doubt the claim?

Comment: It's not unusual for the soviets to use pictures as propaganda tools. In this case Stalin looks a lot more attractive (to my modern eyes) than I'd expect. Here are two comments of a reddit discussion where the uses assume that it's propaganda: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/OldSchoolCool/comments/4ufkks/hot_young_hipster_joseph_stalin_1902/d5pixwh), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/OldSchoolCool/comments/4ufkks/hot_young_hipster_joseph_stalin_1902/d5qfwdo).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Joseph Stalin museum in Gori, Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin_Museum,_Gori) shows many more of his (youth) [photographs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160323140748/http://www.stalinmuseum.ge/eng/gallery/stalin/)<sup>*</sup> - it's unlikely these have all been forged.

The (currently) 4th picture is the one you refer to<sup>*</sup>.

Note: Many of the pictures there are not originals, but copies (and often from newspapers) - very disappointing to look at. Still, given the abundance of pictures there (two or three large rooms full, IIRC), it would be hard to 'insert' just that one being *not* of Stalin but still resembling all the others throughout his life.

<sup>* WebArchive link, http(s)://www.stalinmuseum.ge is dead. The picture refered to is no longer available in that archive.</sup>